# ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "posts" has no column named "user" - where a 'post' belongs_to 'user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, guard, belongs-to

I am trying to create some association tests for a class with a `belongs_to` association.

The test fails when the fixtures are being created - Rails is not detecting the `belongs_to :user` association in `Posts`.

It seems to pass in the regular `rake test` command, but not when the individual file is ran inside `guard`.

The test is below:

```
module Post
  class AssociationsTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    subject { Post.new }
    should belong_to(:user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure out my issue - I think it was because I was using nested module/class definitions for my test, and using the same module name.

The working code was:

```
class Post::AssociationsTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  subject { Post.new }
  should belong_to(:user)
end
```